# How to force Kotlin to call a particular overloaded method in Java interface?

Tags: kotlin, methods, overloading

There is a Java interface

```
interface MyContract {
  
  <M> void execute(Class<M> argClass, Consumer<M> action);

  <M, R> R execute(Class<M> argClass, Function<M, R> action);
}
```

When `execute` method is called from Kotlin code by default compiler always uses the first overloaded method, even when the expected type was explicitly set, there is a compilation error:

```
MyContract myContract = createSomehow();
val x: Int = myContract.execute(SomeClass::class.java, { it -> 1})  

Compilation error:
Type mismatch: inferred type is Unit but Int was expected
```

To force compiler use the second overloaded method I add this boilerplate:

```
val fn: (SomeClass) -> Int = { it -> 1 }
val x: Int = myContract.execute(SomeClass::class.java, fn)
```

**What is a normal syntactical way to express intention to call a particular overloaded method in this case?**

Comment: You can force your second argument to be a function explicitly: `val x = myContract.execute(SomeClass::class.java, Function{ it -> 1 })`.

Comment: You'll also need to `import java.util.function.Function` because `kotlin.Function` is imported by default.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This problem is not java-interop specific, if a similar interface was defined in Kotlin, the error would be the same. Looks like there is room for an overload resolution mechanism enhancement.

For a workaround you may use the fact, that overloaded methods have a different amount of type parameters, so you may specify them explicitly:

```kotlin
val x = myContract.execute<SomeClass, Int>(SomeClass::class.java) { it -> 1 }
```

This is still noisy, so I'd suggest declaring Kotlin-specific API:

```kotlin
internal inline fun <reified M> MyContract.execute(noinline action: ((M) -> Unit)?) = execute(M::class.java, action)
internal inline fun <reified M, R> MyContract.execute(noinline action: ((M) -> R)?) = execute(M::class.java, action)
```

Now it may be called with:

```kotlin
val x = myContract.execute<SomeClass, Int> { it -> 1 }
```

Comment: Looks powerful: 5 ultra features of Kotlin in one shot. Thank you for this answer